# IsNan() function considers certain kind of strings as number - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, casting, nan

I'm checking for `integer` values in `node.js` using `IsNaN` function. 
Unexpectedly, this function validates the strings like `1E267146`, `1E656716` , `914E6583` to be numbers, as these strings are exponential values. Any way to work around this? In actual scenario i wont get any exponential values.

Comment: Those numbers are too big to be managed correctly by JS, so they are evaluated as Infinite. No, there is no way to get them correctly, you have to write them "manually"(but I don't suggest to do something like this)

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844)

Comment: What is your definition of an Integer? for example `1E267146` is a big integer written in scientific notation. javascript otherwise only handles integers in the range MIN_INTEGER = -9007199254740992, MAX_INTEGER = 9007199254740991

Comment: Another question is whether the value should be number-typed or if string values such as `"0"` should be considered integers, too.

Answer (score 3):

[ECMA6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3anumber.isinteger) defines [Number.isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) as follows:

Javascript

```
function isInteger(nVal) {
    return typeof nVal === "number" && isFinite(nVal) && nVal > -9007199254740992 && nVal < 9007199254740992 && Math.floor(nVal) === nVal;
}
```

but this will also accept scientific notation

```
console.log(isInteger(1e6));
console.log(isInteger(+"1e6"));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/cMuaG/)

You need to be clear as to what your definitions/expectations are.

My guess is that you may want something like this, if you are testing strings and have no limits on the max or min integer.

Javascript

```
function isStringNumericalInteger(testValue) {
    return typeof testValue === "string" && /^[\-+]?[1-9]{1}\d+$|^[\-+]?0$/.test(testValue);
}

console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("9007199254740991"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("-123216848516878975616587987846516879844651654847"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("1.1"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("-1.1"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("1e10"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("010"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger("0x9"));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger(""));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger(" "));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger());
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger(null));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger([]));
console.log(isStringNumericalInteger({}));
```

Output

```
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/btAAx/)

If you want to bound the range to what javascript can represent numerically as an integer then you will need to add a test for `&& +testValue > -9007199254740992 && +testValue < 9007199254740992`

If you don't like using RegExs, you can also accomplish this with a parser. Something like this:

Javascript

```
function isCharacterDigit(testCharacter) {
    var charCode = testCharacter.charCodeAt(0);

    return charCode >= 48 && testCharacter <= 57;
}

function isStringNumericalInteger(testValue) {
    var start = 0,
        character,
        index,
        length;

    if (typeof testValue !== "string") {
        return false;
    }

    character = testValue.charAt(start);
    if (character === "+" || character === "-") {
        start += 1;
        character = testValue.charAt(start);
    }

    start += 1;
    length = testValue.length;
    if ((length > start && character === "0") || !isCharacterDigit(character)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (index = start; index < length; index += 1) {
        if (!isCharacterDigit(testValue.charAt(index))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/YZbp5/)

Answer (score -2):

I would use something like below code to validate number input. First I parse the given value to float and then check isNaN().

```
var isNumber = function (obj) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(obj)) && isFinite(obj);
};
```

Comment: I got this answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844

Comment: It checks for numbers, not integers, though.

Comment: Its enough to check for number atleast and not exactly for integer. I have resolved this using !IsFinite() function.

Comment: What rubbish! The OP wants to check for integers and non-scientific integers at that!

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you need in your case (i hate regex because this is not very good for the performance but..)

http://jsbin.com/EQiBada/1/

```
var NMAX = Math.pow(2, 53);
function isNumeric(n) {
  n = n < 0 ? n * -1 : n;
  var r = /^\d+$/.test(n);
  if (r === true)
  {
    return parseInt(n, 10) >= (NMAX * -1) + 1 && parseInt(n, 10) <= NMAX;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Minified

```
var NMAX = Math.pow(2, 53);
function isNumericMin(n) {
  n = n < 0 ? n * -1 : n;
  return /^\d+$/.test(n) === true ? parseInt(n, 10) >= (NMAX * -1) + 1 && parseInt(n, 10) <= NMAX : false;
}
```

Comment: `true` for `10000000000000000000000000000000`, which is clearly too large for an integer.

Comment: Damn, i fix this case

Comment: I meant `'10000000000000000000000000000000'` (string). Also `parseInt` will never return anything that is larger than `MAX_VALUE` or smaller than `MIN_VALUE`. Also you're accepting string in hex or octet notation, because you didn't pass `10` as second parameter to `parseInt`

Answer (score -2):

var i = '1E267146'
  if(isNaN(i) || !isFinite(i) !! i=="")
    {
      // do stuff
    }
 else
    {
     // do stuff 
    }

Comment: But it's the OP's answer to his own question…

Comment: And?!! You think that means it is correct and useful? Further more, why test for `isNaN` and `!isFinite`